# IzPack: get user input then process it in the processpanle

Tags: installation, izpack

H,

I need to get a user input during installation then use it as an argument for an application which is executed in the processPanle. How can I get the variable which contains the user input in the processPanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the variable using `${}` syntax like shown in the following example.

userInputSpec.xml (snippet):

```
<field type="rule" variable="tomcat_http_port">
  <spec txt="HTTP-Port:" id="panel0.field2.label" set="0:80" layout="N:5:5" />
</field>
```

process.xml (snippet):

```
<job name="Launching Browser">
 <executeclass name="edu.ccdb.util.BareBonesBrowserLauncher">
   <arg>http://localhost:${tomcat_http_port}/klaros-web</arg>
 </executeclass>
</job>
```

Comment: Is the variable defined in the userInputSpect XML file accessible in the process XML file?

Comment: Yes, this is what the example tries to demonstrate.